# Hive Convert String Date with PM/AM

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a date string listed as below

```
2015-03-14 11:00:00 AM
```

I am trying to convert this into a timestamp 
I have tried

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(mydate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa') as timestamp) as new_date,
```

and

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(mydate,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa') as timestamp) as new_date,
```

This will always return null

i also tried

```
unix_timestamp(mydate 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa') as new_date
```

this returns a large int number.

How can i convert this string date into a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(mydate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa'))
```